# Keycloak Client Credentials Flow Clarification

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak

I am using **Keycloak** server to implement SSO. I am able to get **access token** for a specific client using **client_credentials** flow.

However, my observation is that the access token is granted for **internal service account** of the **client**. I would like to get **access token** for **other users** present in **realm** by providing some **additional parameter** to the token endpoint.

Below is the **current request** I make to **token endpoint** using **Postman Chrome extension**:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/<protocol>/token

x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type        client_credentials
client_id         <client_id>
client_secret     <client_secret>
```

Please let me know if this possible. Also, I would like to convey that am totally new to **Keycloak** and **openid-connect** protocol.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding some Oauth concepts right here. The *client_credentials* grant should only be used for a service itself to grant access to an specific resource. Imagine this scenario:

End User -> Docs Service -> Docs Repo

The end user has access to some docs stored in the repo through the docs service. In this case, the service makes the decision to grant the user access to a specific document or not, since the repo is a mere content server. Obviously, both of them are secured through two different keycloak clients.

However, the docs service needs to have **full access** to the repo. He can access any document he requests. The solution is to give the docs service a service account role, let's say *DOC_MANAGER* and make the repo check for this role when a resource is requested. The service authenticates with *client_credentials* and gets access to the resource **as a service**.

But the end user will perform a standard login, using the [Authorization code flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication), for example, and get access to the doc through the service. The service will check for another role, let's say *DOC_USER* and check whether the user has access to this concrete resource or not, before going to the repo.

You can read more about keycloak service accounts [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_service_accounts).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It's very clear and understandable. I myself had a similar thought. I asked this because this is the requirement given to me. Now, I confirmed the requirement given to me doesn't make any sense. :-)

Comment: The last link lead me to a 404 page :/

Comment: @Sèb fixed ;-)))

Comment: This does work if you want to have full access to the Docs Repo, but let's say you want to restrict access to the Docs Repo to **just a part of it using rights based on a user in a realm instead of a role specified in the access token**? This does not work. I don't get why the flow could not deliver access tokens to Docs Service using user/password from a realm? Why must we use a client_id and client_secret ?