# keycloak angular get all users

Tags: angular, keycloak

as the title suggest I would like to get a list of all users (username and id) and/or all users who have a specific role.

I am using the `keycloak-angular`-plugin (https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular#readme).

I have already read this article ([How can I read all users using keycloak and spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583361/how-can-i-read-all-users-using-keycloak-and-spring)), thus I apparently need something like a superuser. So far I created a user which has the  the `realm-management` client role as well as the assigned role `view-users`. I can also verify that I have the necessary rights with the `getKeycloakInstance()`-method, however, at that point I am stuck now...

I am not able how to figure out the user list in the object I recieve.

I appreciate any help and thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution?
I'm facing exactly the same issue