# How to get Keycloak user information via REST without admin role

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm using [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) as authorization server. The users send own username/password to `MyWebApp` and `MyWebApp` with `grant_type: password` get the token and then response token to the user. Now I want to my users be able to get their information, change their password and everything related to themselves **RESTFUL**. When I send a rest request to `/{realm}/users/{id}` to get user information, The keycloak get 403 error response. How can I get user information without admin access from keyclaok?

Note: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470477/how-to-get-keycloak-users-via-rest-without-admin-account), But I want to give the user edit profile too.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are using Oauth with Grant type=password. If the token you mentioned is generate by Keycloak. You can request user information to Keycloak using /userinfo endpoint.

This is example of endpoint:

"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"

This is how to send the parameters:
https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api/userinfo

GET /userinfo HTTP/1.1

Host: c2id.com

Authorization: Bearer Gp7b5hiURKpWzEXgMJP38EnYimgxlBC1PpS2zGXUqe

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know in new versions of Keycloak, Account application (`~/auth/realms/{realm}/account`) will be implemented as REST backend so your users will be able to work with their profile data in RESTful way (check out keycloak [blog](https://www.keycloak.org/2019/09/2019-roadmap.html)).

If you can't wait too long for such feature, you could implement your own REST backend for user profile operations. It mean that you have to implement **REST endpoint Service Provider**, and integrate to that API your custom set of Keycloak Roles (Your also may to implement endpoint without checks for any roles, so only bearer authentication required). Check [Keycloak development docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_extensions_rest), also you could use Keycloak sources, especially `org.keycloak.services.resources.admin` package as implementation example.

PS. For viewing user info, consider using User Info OIDC endpoint (See **Hlex** answer). It also could be customized via OIDC mappers (Clients -> {client Id} -> Mappers tab)