# how to get initial access token from keycloak client registration using rest api?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to create a client through REST API, for that i need to pass an intial access token(generated by client registration in keycloak) with my request.

My question here is how can i generate that intial access token through REST API. Can anyone help?

This is the token that I'm passing with my url:
[image]

Here is the screenshot of the response when I try to get the initial access token needed for registering a client by passing a body of parm count and expiration with login token for admin-cli in header:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the initial access token for client registration ,first we need to set the client role of admin-cli as realm-{name} and select client-create from it. Then get the admin bearer token for admin-cli and pass it along with the url for initial access token.

Comment: So basically your admin account was lacking the appropriate privileges?

Answer (score 3):

With a simple GET REST-Request, you can get a token you can use for later requests

```
GET "grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli&username=$USERNAME&password=$PASSWORD" "$HOST/auth/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

as bash (jq must be installed):

```
#get admin bearer token
AUTH_RESPONSE_KC_ADMIN=$(curl  --silent -d "grant_type=password&client_id=admin-    cli&username=$USERNAME&password=$PASSWORD" "$HOST/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token")
if [[ $AUTH_RESPONSE_KC_ADMIN != *"access_token"* ]]; then
  echo "No access token for keycloak admin!"
  echo $AUTH_RESPONSE_KC_ADMIN
  exit -1
fi
TOKEN_KC_ADMIN=$(echo $AUTH_RESPONSE_KC_ADMIN | jq -r '.access_token')
AUTH_TOKEN_KC_ADMIN="Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN_KC_ADMIN"
```

But this access token is only valid for some time (depending on keycloak settings)

To create a client with REST:

```
#use: create_client clientName
function create_client {
  CLIENT='{"enabled":true,"attributes":{},"redirectUris":["*"],"clientId":"'$1'","protocol":"openid-connect", "secret":"'$SECRET'","clientAuthenticatorType":"client-secret","publicClient":"false"}'
  curl -i --silent -d "$CLIENT" -H "$AUTH_TOKEN_KC_ADMIN" -H "$CONTENT_TYPE" $HOST/auth/admin/realms/$REALM/clients | head -1
}
```

Comment: i want to create client through client registration service in keycloak.

Comment: for that i need to get an intial access token, i found the url from keycloak documentation  .  the url that i have passed is .... /auth/admin/realms/master/clients-initial-access...  the body is   {
    "count": 5,
    "expiration": 10
}

Comment: i am also passing the login token as header with the request ....but the response is  403 unknown error.... can you plz help

Comment: maybe this helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470477/how-to-get-keycloak-users-via-rest-without-admin-account?rq=1

Comment: no it didnt work ... i have added the screen shot of the response with the question....hope it will be useful for you to understand my problem

Comment: You are sending a GET request. Shouldn't it be a POST?
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/8.0/rest-api/index.html#_client_initial_access_resource