# Keycloak/OpenID: request user-information on behalf of the client application

Tags: spring, keycloak, openid

I have a Spring Boot-application with a public REST-API. The user authentication is handled by Keycloak. Users can use the API to submit jobs, which are then executed periodically as a Spring Batch. Some of these jobs require the user to be notified via eMail after completion.

The application currently does not store any user-related information, except the ID of the user, who submitted the job. My problem is now, that I need the eMail-address belonging to that User-ID to send the job-completion notification. The JWT passed to the API, which contains this information, can't be used at this time, since the job is executed asynchronous in the batch-context.

I came up with 2 possible solutions so far, which both have their own drawbacks in my opinion:

**solution 1**: extracting the required information from the JWT and persist them in the application's database for later use

drawbacks:

- the application should not be concerned with storing user-information; it also shouldn't duplicate data controlled by other applications
- the user might change its eMail-address in the primary user-database, without getting noticed by my application

**solution 2**: requesting user-details as needed by using Keycloak-APIs.

This looks theoretically like a good approach to me. The suggested solutions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470477/how-to-get-keycloak-users-via-rest-without-admin-account?noredirect=1&lq=1) utilize the Keycloak Admin-API (endpoint `/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{user-id}`) to fetch user-details. This requires the application to be configured as a "confidential client" with own client-credentials and an enabled service account. What bothers me here: It appears a bit strange to me, that a regular application without any special privileges uses an Admin-API. Also, the `users`-endpoint is not restricted to users, which have previously given consent to access their data.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If job requires an e-mail for its completion, why doesn't it request it as start parameter and just keep it in memory?

This is how I would proceed:

- @Controller extracts e-mail from ID token on the end-point from which the user triggers job start
- user e-mail is provided among other parameters to the job
- job completes sending the e-mail
- e-mail is lost, with other job resources

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Unfortunately, this won't solve the problem: The job will be executed periodically (usually once a day), until the user stops it. For this particular task it is expected, that a started job will be running for several years.

Comment: Then, you might have no other choice than persist user subject (not e-mail) and query authorization-server (Keycloak in your case) user-info endpoint using "client credentials" flow to retrieve user e-mail each time a job terminates. Don't store the e-mail because it could change. Subject is permanent.