# How can we obtain an access token for the user by only knowing the username in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, access-token

In my application, users can perform some tasks without login via the keycloak. After performing the task, I want to get an access token from keycloak by giving the username of the user to automatically log the user into application. Assume the user has a registered user account in keycloak too. is there a way to obtain an access token with username only?

Comment: Could you be more specific on Why would you want that?

Comment: Simply I want to obtain an access token from keycloak for a specific username without providing the user password.

Answer (score 1):

> In my application, users can perform some tasks without login via the
> keycloak.

Unless those users are authenticated via some external IDP and you have established a trust-relationship between your external IDP and Keycloak (have a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517248/keycloak-obtaining-access-token-by-user-name-only-without-password) for potential solution for a similar question to yours) in short I would say no.

From [auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens):

> **Access tokens are used in token-based authentication to allow an
> application to access an API. The application receives an access token
> after a user successfully authenticates** and authorizes access, then
> passes the access token as a credential when it calls the target API.

The point is exactly that, exchanging some kind of authentication information (*.e.g.,* username and password, or client secret) for a token that *proves* to your application that the user has authenticated successfully. Otherwise, someone could just enter your system as long as it had access to a username.

It sounds to me that you want to use the access token has means to pass information between Keycloak and your app, for that you have for sure better options.