# springboot keyclaok rest call server to server authentication

Tags: rest, spring-boot, keycloak, bearer-token

I have three services running SpringBoot + Keycloak securtiy as a bearer client each. (Not realy microservices, but it should be one later on)

Now I want service-1 call service-2 with a REST call. But the services REST calls are secured with e.g: service1: `.antMatchers("/service1/**").hasRole("chief")` service2: `.antMatchers("/service2/**").hasRole("chief")` service3: `.antMatchers("/service3/**").hasRole("chief")`
...and so on.

On call GET "/service2/data" from service-1 I get a 401 return code of course.

**What do I need to setup to get this running correctly?**

Can I set up that all bearer-client are allowed to call each other?
Or should I setup a login for the services? or just add roles to the clients?

Comment: It depends on the kind of call. Would the end user have permission to make that kind of transitive call? If yes, then just use `KeycloakRestTemplate`. Otherwise, you'll need to setup a service account in order to service-1 to be able to reach some feature of service-2, logging in with `client_credentials`. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41781426/1199132

Comment: Thanks, good hint. Indeed the original user-call should not have that that permissions directly. But the services between each other.